# Не знаю куда задать вопрос по поиску книги

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, учебные-материалы

Мне нужно найти книгу по программированию, куда задать такой вопрос?
Раньше были форумы на хэшкоде, а вот теперь что-то в ступоре я.
Мне кажется SO на русском не совсем по этой тематике.

**UPD**
Книга Кента Бека

"Экстремальное программирование: разработка через тестирование"

форматы fb2, epub или любой другой текстовый вариант. Не сканы.

Comment: на сайте есть несколько вопросов/ответов в которых сообщество собрало список литературы? [например](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/179270), [например2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/179270)

Comment: @Bald набор литературы не подойдет, я ищу конкретную книгу.

Comment: не поймите меня превратно. а как же [yandex](https://www.yandex.ru/), [google](https://www.google.ru/)

Comment: Есть смысл спросить в IT-сообществах в соцсетях, только не в комментариях, а в обсуждениях, там меньше неконструктива. Если известна направленность книги и по ней есть пост у нас, можно спросить в комментариях к вопросу или ответу, с просьбой добавить в список. И вообще это ответ вышел. .-.

Comment: @Bald они не дали нужный результатов.

Comment: @D-side известен и автор, и название книги. мне нужна конкретная книга в нужном формате. Но нужного формата нет даже в магазинах

Comment: А, то есть, это даже не "вспоминание, что это была за книга", это поиск читабельного экземпляра? Тогда 100% оффтопик. Допишите это в вопрос.

Comment: [RTF](http://kibi.ru/xp/xp) подойдет?

Comment: А вот [online](http://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=69190) с предложением скачать в разных форматах. / Искал в гугле (несколько минут) по запросу -- `экстремальное программирование разработка через тестирование скачать pdf` / Возникает вопрос -- а Вы-то как искали?

Comment: @avp я видел это. это не так книга. прочтите название того, что вы нашли, и того, что мне надо :) Я умею гуглить, не стоит в этом сомневаться.

Comment: @avp  Поясню, у этого автора есть несколько книг серии "Экстремальное программирование", и да, ту что вы нашли, одна книга из этой серии, но я искал другую, которая имеет дополнительное название "разработка через тестирование"

Answer (score 6):

Верно ли я понимаю, что вам нужно найти эту книгу в электронном формате?

> Мне кажется SO на русском не совсем по этой тематике.

Да, совершенно верно. Поиск ссылок на другие сайты — точно не по теме SO (на любом языке). Собственного хранилища файлов здесь нет, да и не планируется.

Тем более, две предложенных вам ссылки ведут на источники, которые нарушают авторские права. И в большинстве случаев с поиском книг будет именно так. Не буду даже пытаться запретить кому-либо пиратить книги, это было бы абсурдно. Но SO для этого не подходит.

Как уже не раз говорилось, для общения вне допустимой тематики вопросов отлично подходят чаты.

Comment: Суть то вопроса заключается в том, чтобы опросить как можно больше людей

Comment: @andreich: и что из этого следует?

Answer (score 4):

C учетом того что данная книга не выходила в *электронном формате* единственная Ваша надежда на то что кто то перевел/переведет данную книгу для себя в текстовый формат и решит поделиться плодами своего труда. За сим предлагаю довольствоваться малым, т.е. читаем от сканированный вариант.

Comment: С чего Вы сразу решили, что книга не выходила в электронных форматах?

Comment: @avp зря вы так, поискав эту книгу, я склонен верить в такой вариант событий.

Comment: @andreich, да, Вы правы. У автора несколько книг с почти одинаковым названием. Нашел pdf с той, какую Вы ищете, но внутри просто скан.